# boost::pool real memory allocations

Tags: c++, boost, memory-pool, boost-pool

I'm trying to use the `boost::pool` memory pool from `#include "boost/pool/pool.hpp"`.
I want to check how much memory is allocated with `boost::pool` so I run the command `system("ps aux | grep myProgramExe | grep -v grep  | awk '{print $5}'");` which gives me the (from the `ps` man page) `VSZ - virtual memory size of the process in KiB (1024-byte units). Device mappings are currently excluded; this is subject to change. (alias vsize).`

I'm getting something strange:

1. Code (*code is indented 4 spaces, plus another 4 because it's embedded in a list*)

   ```
   int main()
   {
       {
           boost::pool<> pool(4, 1);
           system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"1. \" $5}'");
           void *a = pool.malloc();
           pool.free(a);
           system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"2. \" $5}'");
       }
       system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"3. \" $5}'");
   }
   ```

The output is:

```
1. 18908
2. 19040
3. 19040
```

Which is strange, because:
a. I wanted to allocate only 4 bytes (the `next allocation` should be only 1 instance).
b. The memory isn't being free'd when the block is over and `pool` is dead.

2. Now I want to allocate instance of size 128, and I want to allocate 1024 like this in the next allocation:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       {
           boost::pool<> pool(128, 1024);
           system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"4. \" $5}'");
           void *a = pool.malloc();
           pool.free(a);
           system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"5. \" $5}'");
       }
       system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"6. \" $5}'");
   }
   ```

Output:

```
4. 18908
5. 19040
6. 18908
```

Which is fine, because:

a. I wanted to allocate `128 * 1024 = 131072` bytes, and got `19040 - 18908 = 132KB = 135168` bytes. `135168 - 131072 = 4096` bytes (that's just the pool over head, I think).
b. When the block ended, the memory was free'd.

3. destructor

   ```
   int main() {
       {
           boost::pool<> *pool = new boost::pool<>(128, 1024);
           system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"7. \" $5}'");
           void *a = pool->malloc();
           pool->free(a);
           delete pool;
           system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"8. \" $5}'");
       }
       system("ps aux | grep boostHash | grep -v grep  | awk '{print \"9. \" $5}'");
   }
   ```

Output:

```
7. 19040
8. 19040
9. 19040
```

This is strange,
a. For some reason, the size is already allocated (before I called `pool.malloc()`.
b. The size isn't being free'd in `delete`.

Is this explainable?
Do I need to use another tool instead of `ps` to see the memory used by the program?

Comment: What makes you think the program has to return free'd memory to the system? It usually caches it in case it's needed again later. In general, if you want to see exactly what it's doing, you need platform-specific tools. Since you're using `ps`, `grep` and `awk` I'll assume *NIX, in which case you can trace system calls with `strace`, `truss`, `dtrace` or similar. Look for calls to `sbrk`, `mmap`, `munmap` etc.

Comment: I tried to `char *a = new char[1024];` right after it didn't free'd the memory, and the program allocated new memory. instead of reusing the old one...

Comment: Try a memory profiler such as `valgrind --tool=massif`. You're trying to figure out things by looking at 5th-level derivative figures. This is all find and dandy when you want to observe fact about composition of small stars, but believe me, if scientists could just sample them they would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this explainable?

Yes.

> Do I need to use another tool instead of ps to see the memory used by the program?

You *are* seeing the memory used by the program.

What you didn't take into account: memory allocation routines are heavily optimized. Libraries (like libc) will use various strategies to make allocation/reallocation faster, for various scenarios. Here are some common memory management strategies:

- request memory preemptively, from the operating system; this allows the application to perform subsequent internal allocations of the same type, without the cost of requesting more memory from the OS;
- caching released memory; this allows an applications to reuse memory (received from the OS) for subsequent allocations (and again, avoid the overhead of talking with the OS about it)

Comment: But I tried to `char *a = new char[1024];` right after it didn't free'd the memory, and the program did allocated new memory. instead of reusing the old one...

Comment: Basically, unless it is documented, you cannot count on any behavior; It is possible the memory used by the pool is held in some static `boost::???_allocator` instance somewhere (but this is just guessing on my part).